# does file_get_contents(“php://input”); method affect scalability?

Tags: php

When multiple users access the page in php which has file_get_contents("php://input"); method will there be any blocking? I understand that each request makes an new instance, Does the above method makes any blocking on the requests made? Does it use only one stream for all the instances or different stream for different request? I am new to php so please help me in this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`php://input` is symbolic for the input stream provided by the HTTP client. Multiple clients have different input streams, so different clients still can be handled asynchronously. Still, requests can block on this stream, when the client doesn't provide the data fast enough. This issue exists regardless of whether there is one client or one hundred.

Comment: This stream will block only when the data transfer from the client is slow?@Ulrich

Comment: Probably yes. I'm not 100% sure how buffering is handled in this case and it could also depend on the circumstances (which webserver, how that server is configured). Assuming that PHP doesn't wait for the full input up front, which is a reasonable improvement, reading the input could block. It will only block this one request, not other requests.